# QCamera automatically reset my settings

Tags: qt, camera

I'm trying to set a few settings in the [camera example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-camera-example.html)

## Declaration

```
QCamera *camera;
QMediaRecorder* mediaRecorder;
QVideoEncoderSettings videoSettings;
```

## Code

```
videoSettings.setFrameRate(10);
qDebug() << videoSettings.frameRate();
videoSettings.setQuality(QMultimedia::VeryLowQuality);
videoSettings.setResolution(200, 300);
qDebug() << videoSettings.resolution();
mediaRecorder->setVideoSettings(videoSettings);
qDebug() << mediaRecorder->videoSettings().resolution();
```

And it's not working, as you can see the debug log:

```
10
QSize(200, 300)
QSize(-1, -1) 0 // should be 200*300 an 10fps, isn't it ?
```

I don't understand why it's not working...

Comment: In which state is your mediaRecorder when you change its settings?

Comment: @vahancho it's in `QMediaRecorder::StoppedState`